# How do I add the auto panner effect to an audio using javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, audio

I'm creating a website that creates 8d audio, but I'm not finding a way to add the auto panner and reverb effect to the audio.

Please, help me!

add auto panner and reverb effect to the audio using javascript.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.